# Parse - Sign Up and Login at the same time

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Using Parse (iOS framework), I am able to sign up and login successfully using two API.
When user log in, it will cache the user and so accessing "currentUser" will return appropriate object. But sign up API is not caching.
Is there any way that sign up itself will cache the user and avoid separate log in functionality?

Comment: Umm... No code to show us? :-/

Comment: Considered `signUpViewController:didSignUpUser:`?

Comment: @Wain, It works good if PFSignUpViewController is used, but I'm using PFUser's "signUpInBackgroundWithBlock" method. Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

It should automatically log you in as well. For example, if in your completion block in `signUpInBackground`, you have a segue to your main screen and in your main screen, it is supposed to show information related to the user, then it will because `[PFUser currentUser]` is set to the user that registered.

here is an example

```
[user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"] message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [alertView show];
        // Bring the keyboard back up, because they'll probably need to change something.
        [_usernameField becomeFirstResponder];

    }
    else{
    // Success!
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToMain" sender:self];
    }
}];
```

Comment: No, it wont cache "PFUser". Even in documentation its not mentioned about the same.